# Choosing Different Pivot

Tags: c++, quicksort

When i choose pivot the first element of list this code works but for example i want to make last element pivot and i wanna make minumum change in this code so i add swap(arr[high],arr[low]) before pivot=arr[low] i just change the value of low to high.But program stopped run.I don't know why this isn't work.

```
int partition(int low, int high, int arr[])
{
    int pivot = arr[low];
    int i = low;
    for (int j = low + 1; j <= high; ++j)
    {

        if (arr[j] < pivot)
        {
            ++i;
            swap(arr[j], arr[i]);
        }
    }
    swap(arr[low], arr[i]);
    return i;
}

void quickSort(int low, int high, int arr[])
{
    if (low < high)
    {
        int pivot = partition(low, high, arr);
        quickSort(low, pivot, arr);
        quickSort(pivot + 1, high, arr);
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. What is the contents of your array? What does "program stopped run" mean? Did the program crash? If so where did it crash, what was the error code? Have you tried debugging?

Comment: Why don't you just use `std::sort`/`std::partition` and be done with it? Do you *really* have a situation where implementing your own quicksort with custom pivot selection *actually matters*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i just change the value of low to high

If you mean you made this change:

```
    int pivot = arr[high];     // was arr[low]
```

then the code needs to be updated elsewhere. Typical lomuto partion scheme example:

```
int Partition(int arr[], int low, int high)
{
    int pivot = arr[high];
    int i = low;
    for (int j = low; j < high; ++j)
    {
        if (arr[j] < pivot)
        {
            std::swap(arr[j], arr[i]);
            ++i;
        }
    }
    std::swap(arr[i], arr[high]);
    return i;
}

void QuickSort(int arr[], int low, int high)
{
    if (low < high)
    {
        int pivot = Partition(arr, low, high);
        QuickSort(arr, low, pivot-1);
        QuickSort(arr, pivot + 1, high);
    }
}
```